# Is there a script or software to overwrite locally saved html files, so that they get saved with the same name and path?

Tags: html, web, translation, scraping

I have a website i scraped with HTTracker, and it is scraped 1 level deep. HTTracker keeps the website structure, so if i click a link in the mainpage it sends me to another html file also saved in my pc. What i am trying to do is hardcode another language in all these files.

In chrome you can force translate languages, and if you right click then save as, the resulting html file will have the desired language harcoded in the html. I also found an extension called Save Page WE that lets you enter a list of links and download them all, and it also scrolls down all pages to lazy load them which is really needed with these webpages, but it does not maintain the website structure like HTTracker. I'm trying to find a way, maybe a tool or a script, to open all these webpages i already scraped in chrome, re-download them with the new language hardcoded, and have them saved with the same name and to the same path to maintan the structure.

Comment: You should be able to do that with node using JavaScript. Did you try that and it didn't work?

Comment: BTW if you do try and need help stackoverflow is where to ask the code question to make the script work. Be sure you look at "how to ask a good question" and ensure that the answer isn't already there.